# Why Spring Boot project/REST web-service not response into JSON format?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have developed 1-REST web services with help of Spring-Boot technology.

Now, while i am going to requesting any thing it isn't responding me into JSON format ? in stead of it it's responding into plain "String" format.

Also, note i have used annotation @RestController at Controller class level.

Some how i am thinking some configuration i am missing. is it so ?

My current Maven Configuration is ,

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Also, i have noticed that while i am requesting(POST) for getting List then in such case it's returns an array of JSON object.

Can anyone guide me what's wrong with me ?

Comment: Could you provide your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, you want to produce a JSON object in response ?

you have an option in your `@RequestMapping` that `produces` a specific format of response.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Also you can use a specific format of response to add your object to return, and type of response with `ResponseEntity<?>`

something similar to this:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getAll() {
    List<Category> categories = categoryDAO.getAll();
    if (!categories.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(categories, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

i add the annotations for `@PostMapping` it's similar to `@RequestMapping`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/list", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

or also is valid:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/list", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

i'll leave you a link so you can see what properties had `@PostMapping`

[@PostMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html)

Comment: also, if spring version 4.3+, you can simplify your annotation to @PostMapping or another